# How to create complex nested If statement in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an If formula in Excel as seen below:

```
=IF((Q2="O")*AND(R2="O")*AND(S2="O")*AND(T2="O")*AND(U2="O"),"O","X")
```

Basically, if cells Q2 to U2 is O the cell with formula will have O written in it. Otherwise it will have X. Now I want to change it into a nested If statement due to new conditions.

These conditions, in order are:

1. If any one of cells Q2 to U2 = X, cell = X
2. If any one of cells Q2 to U2 = date format, cell = ∆
3. If Q2 to U2 = O, cell = O
4. If none of the conditions are met, the cell will have value "FALSE". (Default appears)

Each of the cells have this condition to follow,

5. If any one of cells Q2 to U2 = -, ignore that cell and count the other cells to get final result.

I tried switching to Or in my original formula to test out conditions 1 and 3.

```
=IF((Q2="O")*or(R2="O")*or(S2="O")*or(T2="O")*or(U2="O"),"O","X")
```

But it doesn't work. Plus I'm not sure how to do condition 5 as well. Any help?

Is it possible to do something so complex  just by using Excel formula? Or do I need to go into VBA?

Comment: What do you mean by 'count' for condition 4? Do you mean get the number of cells without `-`?

Comment: meaning ignore the cells with `-` and get final result. Example if U2 = `-`, carry out condition 1,2 or 3 with cells Q2 to T2.

Comment: Simple answer: Don't. Nested IFs tend to give lots of problems, especially if you (or somene else) wants to maintain the document later on.

Comment: Longer answer: If the business rule is this complex, some business users will want to know which part of the rule lead to the result. Therefore, it might be a good idea to split it up, and put temporary results (with business value) in extra cells. Bonus effect is that  maintenance gets easier.

Comment: What is the exact priority of the last 3 rules? 3-2-4 or 3-4-2 or 4-3-2?

Comment: I updated the question. please take a look.

Comment: You should simplify these conditions into multiple columns, for a number of reasons.  Also, note that you are use `AND` and `OR` incorrectly.  In VBA, you would use "_`argument1`_ `AND` _`argument2`_ `AND` _`argument3`_ `AND …`", however in a worksheet formula the syntax is `AND(`_`argument1, argument2, argument3, …`_`)`.  More info [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things like this are usually easier if you tackle the problem in order of priority. It looks like 1 has the highest priority:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Q2:U2,"X")>0,"X","Does not contain X")
```

`COUNTIF(Q2:U2,"X")` returns the number of occurrences of `X` in the range `Q2:U2`.

In place of "Does not contain X", we can first check for condition 2:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(Q2:U2))>0,"∆","Does not contain X or dates")
```

A date in excel is literally a number with some decorative formatting. I am using `ISNUMBER` to find the numbers and `SUMPRODUCT` to count the identified cells in the range. If there are more than 0 (at least 1), then it will become `∆`.

In place of "Does not contain X or dates" now, we could check for `O`s. I would count the `O`s and add the cells with `-` (conditions 3 and 5 together) and see if they add up to the total cells in `Q2:U2` (which is 5 in this case):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Q2:U2,"O")+COUNTIF(Q2:U2,"-")=5,"O","FALSE")
```

When combined, it would become:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Q2:U2,"X")>0,"X",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(Q2:U2))>0,"∆",COUNTIF(Q2:U2,"O")+COUNTIF(Q2:U2,"-")=5,"O","FALSE"))
```

---

Since all these involve counts, it might be easier setting up helper columns, something like:

```
   | Q | R | S | T | U |       V    |        W       |     X      |     Y      |     Z
1  |   |   |   |   |   | Count of X | Count of dates | Count of O | Count of - | Final value
2  |   |   |   |   |   |       A    |        B       |     C      |     D      |     E
```

A will be:

```
=COUNTIF(Q2:U2,"X")
```

B will be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(Q2:U2))
```

C will be:

```
=COUNTIF(Q2:U2,"O")
```

D will be:

```
=COUNTIF(Q2:U2,"-")
```

E will be:

```
=IF(V2>0,"X",IF(W2>0,"∆",X2+Y2=5,"O","FALSE"))
```

Comment: Looks promising. I'll give it a try and see.